# Installed ubuntu 10.10 on an IBM x40 but can't update!

Tags: 10.10, updates, software-center

I've just brought an IBM think pad x40 of ebay and I've installed ubuntu 10.10.

So far so good.

First things first I loaded up Terminal and typed `sudo apt-get update` but it would't update.

So then I went into software centre and tried installing a game. It hit back with an error message saying it can't connect to the internet.

BUT now, this is rather interesting, because I can surf the web on Firefox with no issues! Has this happened to anyone else and if so how did you solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, Ubuntu 10 is counted as Off Topic because version 10 is not supported any more.

Comment: Try downloading and installing manually the 12.04 or 13.04 versions. Check the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). If you have a problem with the installation look around here or ask a question.

Comment: 10.10 might be the last version that can run on the IBM X40. Newer versions of Ubuntu will result in "This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: pae.
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for you CPU." (http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-1204-on-non-pae.html might solve this problem)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 isn't supported since the 10th of April 2012.

apt-get can't “connect to the Internet” because the 10.10 repositories were shutdown.

You could either install directly a supported Ubuntu version (I'd strongly recommend 12.04 LTS or 13.04 / [download link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)) or manually edit the [repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). (I would strongly discourage you from trying the latter if you don't know what you're doing, tough)